# Transitioning between open close in details element

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to animate the transition between the open/close state of the `<details>` element with just CSS?

Comment: you can try animating the height of it

Comment: Relevant suggestion here also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213329/how-to-add-css3-transition-with-html5-details-summary-tag-reveal

Answer (score 26, accepted):

<del>No, not currently.</del> Yes, but only if you know the `height` or can animate the `font-size`.

Originally, this wasn't the case. From http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/, *"...if you could use CSS transitions to animate the  opening and closing, but we can’t just yet."*  (There is a comment at HTML5 doctor near the end, but it appears to require JS to force the CSS animation.)

It was possible to use different styles based on whether it's opened or closed, but transitions didn't "take" normally. Today, however, the transitions do work if you know the `height` or can animate the `font-size`. See http://codepen.io/morewry/pen/gbJvy for examples and more details.

This was the 2013 solution that kind of fakes it:

**CSS** (May need to add prefixes)

```
/* http://daneden.me/animate/ */
@keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-1.25em);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
.details-animated[open] {
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<details class="details-animated">
    <summary>CSS Animation - Summary</summary>
    Try using [Dan Eden's fadeInDown][1] to maybe fake it a little.  Yay, some animation.
</details>
```

This works today:

**CSS** (May need to add prefixes)

```
.details-animated {
  transition: height 1s ease;
}
.details-animated:not([open]) { height: 1.25em; }
.details-animated[open] { height: 3.75em; }
```

PS: <del>Only tested in Chrome.  Hear FF still doesn't support `details` in general.</del> IE and Edge prior to version 79 still don't support `details`.

(You can use keyframe animations or transitions to do all sorts of other animations for open. I've chosen `fadeInDown` for illustration purposes only. It is a reasonable choice which will give a similar feel if you are unable to add extra markup or will not know the height of the contents. Your options are, however, not limited to this: see the comments on this answer that include two alternatives, including the `font-size` approach.)

Comment: It's a shame it doesn't work. BTW I copied your example in a fiddle and it didn't work, I don't see any change.

Comment: It works for me, but it will only work with `-webkit`, `-moz`, and `-o` (this is a reduced-code example).  I was also editing that up until just now.  Codepen.io has a "prefix free" option for CSS--I don't recall if JSFiddle does? Verify latest code and might want to try adding the prefixes.

Comment: sorry, I didn't check the prefixes.

Comment: Optionally, animate `font-size` like http://stackoverflow.com/a/30531678/923745 for visual expansion.

Comment: That's a good technique to know, but it has issues in this case. First, CSS transitions as used in example don't work, not only because of the `height` issue. Using `opacity: 0` on `details` will hide `summary` and `font-size: 0` will be inherited by `summary`. This makes `summary` invisible when `:not([open])` so it can't be opened (or it jarringly disappears after click). These issues must be worked around with keyframe animations, additional wrapping elements, and additional styles. In cases where that's possible, it does help with height; so thanks! I added it to the pen.

Comment: It works if you apply the animation to `details[open] > summary ~ *`, but requires a container around the collapsible content.

Comment: As I said, "additional wrapping elements"; as that can be a constraint.

Answer (score 13):

My short answer is : you can not transition between summary and the rest of the details content.

**BUT!**

You can do some nice transition inside the summary between the selector **details** and **details[open]**

```css
details{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;height: 100px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100px;height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
details .transition{
  transition: 1s linear;
  transform-origin: right top;
  ;
}
details[open] .transition{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: orangered;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <div></div>
    <div class="transition"></div>
  </summary>
</details>
```

NB : I answer this because it was the first result from googling on this!

Answer (score 4):

Given the height has to snap at some point I prefer to start to animate the height and then snap. If your lucky enough to have all the elements a similar height this solution can be quite effective. (you do need a div inside your details elements though)

```
@keyframes slideDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        height: 20px; /* height of your smallest content, e.g. one line */
    }
}
details {
    max-width:400px;
}
details[open]>div {
    animation-name: slideDown;
    animation-duration: 200ms;
    animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

see http://dabblet.com/gist/5866920 for example

Comment: bad link. please add a snippet to replace it

Answer (score -2):

Of course it's possible:

```css
DETAILS[open] SUMMARY ~ * {
  animation: sweep 3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes sweep {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -10px
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0px
  }
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Summary content</summary>
  Test test test test.
</details>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.