# how to reverse animation using css?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

Hello I was trying to reverse an animation of details and summary. I am able to animate when details is open, when i click again didn't animate in reverse. How to make the animation work when I click summary again? Thank you.
This is my HTML code and CSS

**HTML**

```
<details>
  <summary>I am awesome</summary>
  <p>Hi there this is an awesome paragraph</p>
</details>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;

  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

details {
  background: mistyrose;
  padding: 4em;
  width: 20rem;
}

details:not(open) summary~* {
  animation: anim-rev .5s ease-in;
}

details[open] summary~* {
  animation: anim .5s ease-in;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: -50px;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-rev {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transitioning between open close in details element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301282/transitioning-between-open-close-in-details-element)

Comment: @alotropico that's not an answer I'm looking for. Have you try my code? My code is able to animate when details has open attribute. What am I looking for is to reverse the animation when details clicked again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like 'details' element has some limitations, I was unable to do the close animations properly with such element.

**Instead** I used a bit JQuery and made a div with an ID. You can check the working code below: (I modified your code as little as possible)

https://jsfiddle.net/Aljaz_code/265f0nkb/1/

JQuery code used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#details").click(function(){
        $("#details").toggleClass("closeclass");
    });
});
```

Symbol for the triangle

```
content: "\25BC";
```

Displays a pointing cursor before clicking

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Comment: Ah.. I see. Thanks man. This is what i'm looking for